# How can I add geographic information to the data for the entire Arctic?

Tags: python, geometry, geolocation, gdal

I would like to add geographic information to this dataset [here](https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.854411)and turn it into a geotiff. This dataset has data for the entire Arctic and a corresponding latlonmap in NETCDF format.
I tried gdal_translate but it did not work.

I have also listed the data on google drive[text](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14Wf3TOm4p1bH5c0tJmxMMm0pG19CR7ei?usp=sharing)

gdal_translate -of "GTiff" -a_srs EPSG:4326 -135.001 60.444 45.003 60.430 lead.tif out.tif

The coordinates for the four corners used in gdaltranslate were the upper left and lower right coordinates from latlonmap.nc

I tried EPSG:4326, but is it appropriate for the Arctic-wide dataset in the first place?

Comment: what are the dimension for the given .nc file?

Comment: The data isn't delivered in EPSG:4326, so you can't just assign that projection.

Comment: @Muhammad Umar it has 2798×2798 dimensions

Comment: @RutgerKassies what do you think EPSG of this data? I have read an article of this, but I I couldn't figure out how to project.

Comment: The website mentions `ESPG:3413` and it looks like it has a central longitude of -90. But the metadata on that site it a little vague, no information on the extent for example.